# vim YouComplete for big frameworks

Tags: vim, tensorflow, youcompleteme

I am switching to Vim from Sublime text. My problem is "you complete me". I want to use it however, every time when i use it with big frameworks, it waits significant time to find the suggestions. For numpy it usually takes 10 seconds. I could not wait to see the results for tensorflow. Is there a method for saving the suggestions and use it without every time re discover the member functions and variables?